# hdf5 error when loading data

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe, hdf5, lstm

I'm trying to get to understand (and build off) [BVLC/caffe PR#4681](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/4681).

For this, i've written my own dummy data generation. However, when trying to run training, the file is not loaded at all, due to the following error

> F0302 11:40:20.412214 10108 hdf5.cpp:50] Unsupported datatype class: H5T_ENUM

Following is my code for the proto & for the data gen itself :

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "seq_ind"
  top: "labels"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "dummy_data.txt"
    batch_size: 40
  }
}

layer {
  name: "lstm1"
  type: "LSTM"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "seq_ind"
  top: "lstm1"
  recurrent_param {
    # num + 1 for blank label! (last one)
    num_output: 40
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "lstm1"
  top: "ip1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.1
    }
    axis: 2
  }
}

layer {
  name: "rev1"
  type: "Reverse"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "rev_data"
}

layer {
  name: "lstm2"
  type: "LSTM"
  bottom: "rev_data"
  bottom: "seq_ind"
  top: "lstm2"
  recurrent_param {
    # num + 1 for blank label! (last one)
    num_output: 40
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "lstm2"
  top: "ip2"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.1
    }
    axis: 2
  }
}

layer {
  name: "rev2"
  type: "Reverse"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "rev2"
}

layer {
  name: "eltwise-sum"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "ip1"
  bottom: "rev2"
  eltwise_param { operation: SUM }
  top: "sum"
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "CTCLoss"
  bottom: "sum"
  bottom: "seq_ind"
  bottom: "labels"
  top: "ctc_loss"
}

import numpy as np
import h5py
import functools

def reduce_f(x,y):
    if y:
        x[-1] += 1
    elif x[-1] != 0 : 
        if x[-1] < 3:
            x[-1] = 1
        elif x[-1] < 6:
            x[-1] = 2
        else:
            x[-1] = 3
        x.append(0)
    return x

def label_gen(data):
    res = functools.reduce(reduce_f,data,[0])
    return res[:-1]

def store_hdf5(filename, mapping):
    """Function to store data mapping to a hdf5 file

    Args:
        filename (str): The output filename
        mapping (dic): A dictionary containing mapping from name to numpy data
                       The complete mapping will be stored as single datasets
                       in the h5py file.
    """

    print("Storing hdf5 file %s" % filename)
    with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as hf:
        for label, data in mapping.items():
            print("  adding dataset %s with shape %s" % (label, data.shape))
            hf.create_dataset(label, data=data)

    print("  finished")

def generate_data(T_, C_, lab_len_):
    """Function to generate dummy data

    The data is generated non randomly by a defined function.
    The sequence length is exactly T_.
    The target sequence will be 1 if there are less than 3 continuous 1s
                                2 if less than 6
                                3 otherwise

    Args:
        T_ (int): The number of timesteps (this value must match the batch_size of the caffe net)
        C_ (int): The number of channgels/labels
        lab_len_(int): The label size that must be smaller or equals T_. This value
            will also be used as the maximum allowed label. The label size in the network
            must therefore be 6 = 5 + 1 (+1 for blank label)

    Returns:
        data (numpy array): A numpy array of shape (T_, 1, C_) containing dummy data
        sequence_indicators (numpy array): A numpy array of shape (T_, 1) indicating the
            sequence
        labels (numpy array): A numpy array of shape (T_, 1) defining the label sequence.
            labels will be -1 for all elements greater than T_ (indicating end of sequence).
    """
    assert(lab_len_ <= T_)

    # this is an arbitrary function to generate data not randomly

    data = np.random.rand(T_,C_) > 0.3
      # The sequence length is exactly T_.
    sequence_indicators = np.full(T_, 1, dtype=np.float32)
    sequence_indicators[0] = 0

    # The label lengh is lab_len_
    labels = np.asarray(label_gen(data))
    labels = np.append(labels,[-1]*(T_-labels.size))


    return data, sequence_indicators, labels


if __name__=="__main__":
    # generate the dummy data
    # not that T_ = 40 must match the batch_size of 40 in the network setup
    # as required by the CTC alorithm to see the full sequence
    # The label length and max label is set to 5. Use 6 = 5 + 1 for the label size in the network
    # to add the blank label
    numdatas = 100
    datas = []
    seq_inds = []
    labelsarr = []
    for _ in np.arange(numdatas):
        data, sequence_indicators, labels = generate_data(40, 1, 3)
        datas.append(data)
        seq_inds.append(sequence_indicators)
        labelsarr.append(labels)
    datas = np.asarray(datas)
    datas = np.swapaxes(datas,0,1)
    seq_inds = np.asarray(seq_inds)
    seq_inds = np.swapaxes(seq_inds,0,1)
    labelsarr = np.asarray(labelsarr)
    labelsarr = np.swapaxes(labelsarr,0,1)

    # and write it to the h5 file
    store_hdf5("dummy_data.h5", {"data" : datas, "seq_ind" : seq_inds, "labels" : labelsarr})
```

Comment: use `np.concatnate` instead of `np.asarry` to convert lists to numpy arrays when generating hdf5 file.

Comment: @Shai unfortunately, the CTC PR currently doesn't support having multiple sequences in a training example (in those case, it just takes the first one). :V
The data type problem was fixed by casting the data to int (instead of boolean). Not sure why that was considered an H5T_ENUM data.